# How to force compile error for api method that is not in minSdkVersion

Tags: android

I've been getting NoSuchMethodException crashes on older devices and I'm wondering why the eclipse IDE isn't giving me at least a warning for using methods that aren't supported yet on older devices. I have the minSDKVersion field set in my AndroidManifest.xml correctly. Is there anyway to get a compile error or at least a warning if I use a method that can't be run on minSdkVersion devices?

I've got the following in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" >
</uses-sdk>
```

I don't want to have to test every screen and function of this huge app with an old device.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Lint check for NewApi and InlineApi to errors.

```
right click project --> Properties --> Android Lint Preferences.
```

Find `NewApi` and `InlineApi` and set the `Severity` box to Error or Fatal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lint. Android Lint is a new tool introduced in ADT 16 (and Tools 16) which scans Android project sources for potential bugs. It is available both as a command line tool, as well as integrated with Eclipse

If you use a method that can't be run on minSdkVersion , the lint will yell saying that the method cannot be used.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html

Usage with eclipse

http://tools.android.com/recent/neweclipselintui

List of checks provided

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

Wrtiing custom lint rules

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules

### UsesMinSdkAttributes

Summary: Checks that the minimum SDK and target SDK attributes are defined

Priority: 9 / 10
Severity: Warning
Category: Correctness

The manifest should contain a  element which defines the minimum
minimum API Level required for the application to run, as well as the target
version (the highest API level you have tested the version for.)

More information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html